# All Time Lftp Mirroring

Tags: mirroring, lftp

How to make lftp run in background all time and push any change made to a local folder to a folder on remote server.
The normal reverse mirror command isn't working for all time and specific to changes. 
Basically I want to keep both the folders in sync.
Thanks

Comment: Have you consider to run it via cron? Or to use rsync to minimize the traffic?

Comment: How to do with cron? Also rsync will not work with ftp

Comment: You can tunnel rsync via ssh. You can set in cron script, which ill run lftp (every 5 minutes for example) and exec command to upload files/directories

Comment: Can you post the code or link?

Comment: Here is example command to rsync via ssh local dir to remote dir: rsync -avz -e ssh /local/path user@remote-host:/remote/path

Comment: Hey its ftp I asked for cron code

Comment: the cron record can be something like: */5 * * * * /path/to/script. In to the script you should take care about not to run two instances of lftp (if ftp process take more than 5 minutes)

Comment: I aksed a code not explanation please

Answer (score 1):

Use the mirror function and a cron to trigger it repeatedly.

Put this in a script (e.G. `~/push_to_server.sh`):

```
cd [PATH_THAT_YOU_WANT_TO_COPY]
lftp -c "open [HOST] -u [USER],[PASSWORD]; mirror -R [PATH_ON_SERVER]"
```

You want to look up the '-e' and '-P' funcion of lftp mirror in your manual (`man lftp`) and might use them together with `-R`.

Now you activate that script every few minutes with cron. Run `crontab -e` and add:

```
*/5 * * * * ~/push_to_server.sh
```

That will start the script every 5 minutes (please do read `man 5 crontab` to understand what the 5 and the asterisks are actually doing before changing them). Be sure to point to the actual path of the script in case you moved it or running crontab as a different user.

If your ftp sync takes longer then 5 minutes (at peak times) you have to change the cron. Read `man 5 crontab` to learn how to do that.